# how do you extend the stack element in the dom?

Tags: javascript, dom, html

am extending `Element`s successfully, eg,

```
Element.prototype.ancestorByTagName = function( tagName ) { ... }
```

but cannot figure out how to extend specifically the `Select` element

for example, each of the following fails:

```
Select.prototype.appendOption = function( value, label, select_value ) { ... }
Element.Select.prototype.appendOption = function( value, label, select_value ) { ... }
```

am at a loss.

in this case it makes sense to limit the new method `appendOption` it to `Select` versus all `Element`s, since only `Select` can have `Option` children. `Select`'s `add` method is pretty lame as well.

Comment: Which browser are you targeting? Expecting all browsers to implement the same inheritance model, or any inheritance model, is a bit ambitious. Have you read Kangax's *What’s wrong with extending the DOM* (http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/)?

Comment: Interesting. http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-94282980

Comment: @RobG - after chrome and maybe firefox a little later.  absolutely agree as to dangers of extending dom - most of the time use naming constructs to isolate work.  in this case an intellectual exercise on my part, filling in what I perceive to be holes very basic dom functionality

Comment: @mplugjan - this is another one of those things that I don't understand: to extend an element you use "Element", not "HTMLElement" - I do not understand the naming conventions here

Comment: Just remember that the DOM specifications are for interfaces and are supposed to be language neutral. While they infer a certain inheritance scheme, the DOM may not actually implement or expose any kind of inheritance. In some ways I think that's a good thing - if adding methods to DOM object prototypes becomes popular, there will be a turf war among script libraries to grab the best names - show, hide, add, delete, etc. and I expect shadowing of properties to become a big issue very quickly. Putting two different libraries in the same page would become an even bigger issue than it is now.

Comment: @RobG - yes and yes.  on the other hand, it's a _lot_ cleaner code.  have huge problems with the javascript libraries that use the $(wrapper) around elements - just butt ugly.  I think eventually javascript will have a good K&R chapter 7.  in the meantime I'll keep good notes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure where you got `Element.Select` from but it's not a native object. You want `HTMLSelectElement` instead ([MDC reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLSelectElement)).

---

**Note**: do read [this article](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/), as pointed out in the comments, on why **not** to extend the DOM.

Comment: you're right, and I feel pretty stupid about this.  was using "Element" instead of "HTMLElement" from examples, and got myself confused.

Comment: read article on extending DOM.  at the end it says that in a monolithic environment it might be ok - chrome and later firefox.  if somebody pays me a lot of money I'll pay someone to write a translation into IE.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that worked in Firefox 4

```
<script>
if (HTMLSelectElement)  HTMLSelectElement.prototype.addOption = function(text,value) {
  this.options[this.options.length]= new Option(value,text)
}
else alert("It's not called HTMLSelectElement")
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById('sel1').addOption("Hi","There")
}
</script>
<select id="sel1"></select>
```

and gave me this in IE8

Webpage error details

```
Message: 'HTMLSelectElement' is undefined
Line: 2
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/TEMP/addoption.html
```